# Recording Audio without interrupt background media playing

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

Is it possible to record audio on iOS without interrupt background media playing (like, music)?

If it's possible, what kind of AVAudioSession category and mode should be used, aslo the AVAudioRecorder settings?

The code which won't work I use for now is:

```
do {
    try session.setCategory(.record, options: [.mixWithOthers])
    try session.setActive(true)
    let settings = [
        AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
        AVSampleRateKey: 44100,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
    ]
    audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: genPath(), settings: settings)
} catch let error {
    alert(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription)
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the **sessionCategory** to **.playAndRecord**:

```
session.setCategory(.playAndRecord, options: [.mixWithOthers, .allowAirPlay, .allowBluetoothA2DP])
```

Refer by - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23586056/audio-interruption-when-ios-application-is-recording-in-background)

Comment: Question updated. It's not about start recording in background.

Comment: Changing to `session.setCategory(.playAndRecord, options: [.mixWithOthers, .allowAirPlay,  .allowBluetoothA2DP])` solve the issue

Comment: I'm using this and I can start recording and the already playing audio (if playing over the speaker), will continue playing over the speaker. It isn't a problem for this answer, but transcription using the Speech framework is very flaky, but works great in some scenarios.         try! audioSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord, options: [.mixWithOthers, .allowAirPlay, .allowBluetoothA2DP, .defaultToSpeaker ])